# Please blacklist "The question says it all" in question bodies

Tags: feature-request, questions, question-quality, quality-filter

Multiple times a day I see questions starting with

> The question says it all.

as the first sentence of the body. Current example:

[Why Doesn't Case 1 Do Basically The Same Thing As Case 2 (Except Different Cost)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57221679/why-doesnt-case-1-do-basically-the-same-thing-as-case-2-except-different-cost)

This to me seems to be a sure sign for

- the question being of low quality,
- no question being actually asked in the body,
- the question soon being heavily downvoted or closed.

I **suggest** that the tools scanning the content of a new question for evil words is trained to discover this and prompt the users to

- remove '*The question says it all*' and
- to make sure they *really* are asking a question.

Comment: The question is not of that low quality but just needs editing.

Comment: Blacklisting just ends up with people writing "the questi0n says it all" or some other nonsense to get around the blacklist. People already do it extensively when encountering the no links without code block and other blacklists we have.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm sure it stops some people. Metrics would be helpful, but I'm not sure they log that kind of thing.

Comment: @TylerH Here's a statistic for you, 1574 non-deleted questions containing [probelm](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=probelm&mixed=0) in the title.

Comment: @RobertLongson That's a mildly interesting statistic at best.

Comment: @TylerH It's an example, you can find lots more sadness if you look for the other things we blacklist.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22The%20question%20says%20it%20all%22%20is%3aq

Comment: So disappointed the question body here wasn't *The questions says it all*. A missed opportunity. Please do better next time.

Answer (score -13):

100% disagree.

These types of titles might often hint at extremely low-quality here, but there are several other stack exchanges where some of my questions are easily summed up in their title and there's little else required other than "Title says it all" and proof of due diligence that I searched for answers.

Comment: I don't see how *not* supplying information is proof that you've done research.

Comment: +1 upvoted this answer